# How to get the “shareable link” of a Google Drive file via Google Apps Script and paste the link into a cell in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that makes a PDF of my invoice and sends it to a Google drive folder.Now I want to get the "Shareable link" from the file it just made and paste it into a specific Cell in google Sheets. I don't have a coding background and at most I can understand and modify some code. So I'm using code I found online to create the PDF. I tried making my own code for the shareable link but I'm getting nowhere. Can anyone help me. This is the code I'm using for the PDF. If I can provide any more useful information please let me know. Thank you! :)

````
  
  // Get the currently active spreadsheet URL (link)
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Invoice");

  //Creating an exportable URL
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SS_ID/export?".replace("SS_ID", ss.getId());
  var folderID = "#### Folder ID ####"; // Folder id to save in a folder.
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var invoiceNumber = ss.getRange("'Invoice'!I16").getValue()
  var InvoiceDate = ss.getRange("!I17").getValue()
  var pdfName = "Invoice #"+ invoiceNumber + " - " + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-7", "MM-dd-yyyy");

  /* Specify PDF export parameters
  From: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3579
  */
  var url_ext = 'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'        // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
  + '&size=letter'                       // paper size legal / letter / A4
  + '&portrait=true'                    // orientation, false for landscape
  + '&fitw=true&source=labnol'           // fit to page width, false for actual size
  + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
  + '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
  + '&fzr=false'                         // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
  + '&gid=';                             // the sheet's Id
    
  // Convert individual worksheet to PDF
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + sheet.getSheetId(), {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
    }
  });
  
  //convert the response to a blob
  var blobs = response.getBlob().setName(pdfName + '.pdf');
  
  //saves the file to the specified folder of Google Drive
  var newFile = folder.createFile(blobs);
  
  // Define the scope
  Logger.log("Storage Space used: " + DriveApp.getStorageUsed());

}```
````

Comment: Do you want the link only for accessing the file yourself or for sharing with other people?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intuitively, you can achieve a lot only by yourself, and this is the way to go at the beginning:

You want to retrieve the link of the pdf, so you know for sure that it can happen only when the pdf has been created, which is after this line `var newFile = folder.createFile(blobs);`

Therefore `newFile` is the PDF you've created, what's left is just to get the link of this file, you can use either `getUrl()` or `getId()`:

`var newFileLink = newFile.getUrl()`

or

`var newFileLink = "http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=" + newFile.getId()`

Now you have stored the link of the created PDF, and you want to write data into your spreadsheet within a *specific cell*, maybe you want it in J16, since you're using `invoiceNumber = ss.getRange("'Invoice'!I16").getValue()` to get a value from I16

Assuming you want to set a value in J16. Intuitively again, since `getValue` retrieve something, so maybe something link `setValue` will do the opposite:

`var writePDFLink =  ss.getRange("'Invoice'!J16").setValue(newFileLink)`

Hope this was insightful.

Comment: Thank you so much for not only writing the code but  going out of your way and explaining everything. I really appreciate the help!! Thank you! :)

Comment: Wonderful answer - both content and presentation.